# PHP REG EXP backtrack issue

Tags: php, regex, optimization, pcre, backtracking

I'm trying to use this reg exp in PHP in a preg_match_all

```
/\d+ (?:<[^>]+>)(?:<[^>]+>)(\S+.*\S+)(?:<[^>]+>)\s*(\S+) (?:L|R)\s*\w* \w*\s*(?:\w+\s*){14}(\d+)\s*(\d)\s*(\d*\xA0*\d{3}\xA0*\d{3})/is
```

There's some data sample :

```
38 <A NAME="Philip McRae"><A HREF="xtrastats.html#Philip McRae">Philip McRae</A>            C L  OK    58 71 69 49 33 89 71 45 48 69 50 35 32 61   21   3    787 000
43 <A NAME="Alexander Nikulin"><A HREF="xtrastats.html#Alexander Nikulin">Alexander Nikulin</A>       C L  OK    41 68 71 40 28 90 67 29 31 60 31 37 34 50   26   0      0 000 <a href="http://www.hockeydb.com/ihdb/stats/pdisplay.php?pid=78680" target="_blank">HDB</a>
20 <A NAME="Christian Hanson"><A HREF="xtrastats.html#Christian Hanson">Christian Hanson</A>        C R  OK    57 72 71 54 33 79 70 42 45 71 46 40 36 60   25   1    875 000 <a href="http://www.hockeydb.com/ihdb/stats/pdisplay.php?pid=73824" target="_blank">HDB</a>
```

I got around 1500 lines.

I need to match this :

```
Philip McRae, C, 21, 3, 787 000 (Name, Position, Age, Contract Lenght, Salary)
```

Each time I run my code, I got an Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded error.

After some search I add this line at top of my script but that's not solve my problem

```
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit",10000000);
```

Anyone can help me with this reg exp for some optimisation ?

Regards.

Patrick

Comment: We need to know what you want the expression to do to help you with it.

Comment: Added data sample in my quesiton.

Comment: I didn't get any matches with that regex in the data sample. have you tested with smaller amounts of data?

Comment: @jared you test it on Windows or Linux ? On Windows, remplace\xA0 by .(dot)

Comment: Using regular expressions to match stuff this complex smells bad to me in general.

Why not split it down into several smaller regular expressions and use a state machine? Regular expressions were not built to parse the tag structure of HTML.

Also, what about using DOMDocument to parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not attempt to rewrite your regular expression since we do not have the requirements, but the main issue here is your name group:

```
(\S+.*\S+)
```

The `.*` is greedy.  Meaning it will consume as much as it can including what you're expecting the rest of your expression to match, and it doesn't stop there. Since you have the `/s` pattern modifier, the dot will also match newlines, allowing `.*` to consume the entire file before trying to match `\S` and beginning its long backtracking journey.

One solution is to make the `.*` lazy with `?`, i.e. `.*?` but since you know the name is contained within an element you can simply use a negated character class for the entire group:

```
([^<]*)
```

That should fix your issue, but you probably do not want to be using the `/s` pattern modifier in this case or you should at least add beginning and end of line anchors to your pattern.  You should also try to limit your use of `*`.

Please see:
[Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and 
[Watch out for greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html%20%22Repeat)

Comment: Solve my problem, see my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself!  Three of my favorite rules of thumb: don't use `*` when you mean `+`; don't use the dot (`.`) as your first resort; and if you *do* use the dot, don't use single-line/DOTALL mode.

Answer (score 1):

Even you have around 1 500 lines, the problem you like to solve is per each line.

If you are able to process the input *line by line* you have already reduced the problem by a fair amount.

```
$file = new SplFileObject($path);
foreach ($file as $i => $line) {
    printf("#%'0-4d: %s\n", $i, $line);
}
```

This is just an example, naturally, the regular expression engine itself can do something similar with it's multiline modifier (m). However if you do the foreach above, you could `break` directly for testing with the first line:

```
foreach ($file as $i => $line) {
    printf("#%'0-4d: %s\n", $i, $line);
    $pattern = '(^\d++ <A NAME="([^"]++)"><A HREF="xtrastats.html#Philip McRae">Philip McRae</A>            C L  OK    58 71 69 49 33 89 71 45 48 69 50 35 32 61   21   3    787 000)$';
    $r = preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);
    if (FALSE === $r) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf("Regex failed (%d)", preg_last_error());
    }
    if (!$r) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf("Pattern does not match."));
    }
    var_dump($matches);
    if ($i > 0) break; # exit foreach after X lines.
}
echo "Done.\n";
```

As you can see in this example, the pattern is yet incomplete, but you work out from the full line replacing step by step.

It also makes use of an anchor for the beginning of the string (`^`) and for the end of the string (`$`).

It also makes use of possessive quantifiers (`+`) so that if those don't match, no backtracking occurs (similar to atomic grouping, but easier to write).

Continue to improve your regular expression pattern step by step. If the regex does not compile, an exception is thrown. As well as when a line does not match.

You should get your stuff done after some time, improve the error handling and create some stable an efficient code in the long run.

Comment: Solve my problem, see my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

@hakre and @bodhizero

With your input and your help I've modify my regexp to this :

```
\d{1,2}+ (?:<[^>]++>)(?:<[^>]++>)([^<]*+)(?:<[^>]++>)\s*+(\S{1,2}+) (?:L|R)\s*+\w*+ \w*+\s*+(?:\w++\s*+){14}(\d{1,2}+)\s*+(\d)\s*(\d*+.*?\d{0,3}+.*?\d{3}+)(?: <[^>]++>[^<]*+<[^>]++>)*?
```

The results : parse the entire file in about 2 seconds !!!

I use the [Regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html) program and help me a lot.

I wish I was able to put two answers, but I can't

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the amount of data being used to regex match, or change the `set_time_limit` and `memory_limit` limits.

`preg_match_all()` is very CPU intensive, and depending on how powerful your server CPU is, it can cause execution time and memory problems.

one solution is add this to the top of your code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Your other option is limiting the script to less `preg_match_all()` matches per page load.

Comment: The `preg_*` methods are just a facade for the PCRE regex library, and it works fine as long as the regexes are reasonably well written.  If your code bogs down upon entering one of the `preg_*` methods, it's overwhelmingly likely that the regex is to blame.  If you can't find the cause for it in the regex, get someone to help you look, because it's in there.  But don't just throw more resources at it.